# How to write string in string in remote server and use apostrophe in python?

Tags: python, string, ssh, paramiko

I used ssh using paramiko in python. I want to create the below statement in a directory on my remote Linux server.

```
- sudo echo {"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]} > /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

But when I do this, apostrophes (") are not occurring in the specified file. The file is created as follows. {insecure-registries:[IP:5000]
How can I write this as containing "?

Comment: This is not a [tag:python], [tag:ssh] nor [tag:paramiko] question. Did you test the command in shell? It won't there work either. This is a pure [tag:shell] question.

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't related to Python, SSH or Paramiko directly at all, you're being screwed by the shell's quoting rules here.

If you try to run that command (without the redirection and the sudo) in your own machine's shell, you'll see

```
$ echo {"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]}
{insecure-registries:[IP:5000]}
```

Use single quotes for a more verbatim quoting:

```
- sudo echo '{"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

i.e.

```
$ echo '{"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]}'
{"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]}
```

EDIT based on comment: if you want a string to contain the above, the neatest is to use triple quotes:

```
value = """- sudo echo '{"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json"""
```

or you can use single quotes and escape the single single quotes within:

```
value = '- sudo echo \'{"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]}\' > /etc/docker/daemon.json'
```

Comment: ok but I want to use this statement as a string. So when I type like this,  value = "sudo echo '{"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json" python doesnt allow because of syntax. when ı type like; value = 'sudo echo "{"insecure-registries":["IP:5000"]}" > /etc/docker/daemon.json' the file created like this -> {insecure-registries:[IP:5000]}
how do i get over it?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: thnk you :) it solves my problem